# Google Cloud-How to access and edit .htaccess on Wordpress Bitnami on google-cloud-platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, htaccess

If anyone can please guide me on
How to edit .htaccess file in WP-Bitnami installation on Google cloud platform.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you can edit it via SSH, file is located inside apps/wordpress/htdocs folder, type ls -a to show list of also hidden files/folders